# inverse X and Y axis using geom_ribbon in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

is it possible to use geom_ribbon from the package ggplot2, but with the range plotted horizontally and not vertically. This would be trivial if "geom_ribbon" proposed the options xmin/xmax, but this is not the case.

Here is my data, a simplified plotting function for testing and the figure I obtain. So in this example, I would like to have the "depth" axis displayed vertically.

```
prof <- read.table(text = " depth prop mean error
1 5 FALSE 2.12 0.035
2 15 FALSE 2.06 0.035
3 25 FALSE 1.54 0.035
4 35 FALSE 0.92 0.033
5 45 FALSE 0.71 0.028
6 55 FALSE 0.60 0.026
7 65 FALSE 0.54 0.024
8 75 FALSE 0.49 0.023
9 85 FALSE 0.46 0.022
10 95 FALSE 0.43 0.022
11 105 FALSE 0.41 0.022
12 115 FALSE 0.39 0.021
13 5 TRUE 2.18 0.061
14 15 TRUE 2.11 0.061
15 25 TRUE 1.58 0.054
16 35 TRUE 0.97 0.047
17 45 TRUE 0.76 0.042
18 55 TRUE 0.67 0.043
19 65 TRUE 0.61 0.040
20 75 TRUE 0.54 0.033
21 85 TRUE 0.48 0.028
22 95 TRUE 0.45 0.027
23 105 TRUE 0.43 0.025
24 115 TRUE 0.40 0.022", header=TRUE)

ggplot(prof, aes(colour = prop, fill = prop)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = depth, ymin = mean-error, ymax = mean+error), 
  alpha = 0.6, colour = NA)
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have look at coord_flip() This is untested since you didn't provide the data in an easy format. Post the output of dput(your.data.frame) to provide data.

```
ggplot(prof, aes(x = depth, ymin = mean - error, ymax = mean + error, 
    fill = prop)) + geom_ribbon() + coord_flip()
```

andpleaseusethelargebaratthebottomofyourkeyboardwhentypingcodewhitespacemakestextmuchmorereadablecodeisalsotext

Comment: +1 especially for the last paragraph (although you should also get it because your answer works).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I need, along with scale_x_reverse()